# Why don't styles applay in Laravel 7 if I have folder, that contains my files, named css?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-7

I came across a rather strange behavior in Laravel that I can't exactly explain.

In my public directory, I have a folder named css. In my code, I link to this folder normally:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

However this does not apply my styles. When I change the directory name to styles instead of css. And I properly link style folder with the new directory name the issue is resolved and my styles are applied.

```
<link href="{{ asset('styles/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can check source code right here: 
https://github.com/domenHren27/LravelAuthEx

Comment: Is the name styles not already predefined as folder with css files?

Comment: No, it is css. That is why it is strange if I name it in anything else like "something" or "clow" It will still work the only thing that bothers him is directory name css.

Comment: Can you please put the link in the source code

Comment: It's not just a caching issue? Have you tried doing `"{{ asset('css/app.css') . '?v=1' }}"` ?
And you sure Mix isn't interfering with the css folder?
And you don't have any @import's in the CSS that might break with changing the folder name?